Change of Coordinates and Implications to Partial Derivatives
I have a system of PDEs that switch between the Cartesian coordinate frame $(x,y)$ and the coordinates along an obstacle $(l,n)$, where $l$ is tangential to the obstacle and $n$ is normal to it. The equations to link these coordinates are given by:
$$ x=l \cos{\delta} - n\sin{\delta}, \qquad y=l \sin{\delta} + n \cos{\delta} $$
or inversely,
$$ l = x \cos{\delta} + y \sin{\delta}, \qquad n=-x\sin{\delta}+y\cos{\delta} $$
where $\delta=\arctan{\frac{ds}{dx}}$. My question is how do you systematically determine how a partial derivative would translate to the other coordinate axis? Is it correct that:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial l} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial l}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial l}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
So now I just need to find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial l}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial l}$. To find the former, I take the first equation solved for $x$ and implicitly differentiate assuming everything but $x,l$ are constant. Therefore:
$$ \partial x = \cos{\delta}\ \partial l \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial l}=\cos{\delta} $$
Doing the same thing with the equation solved for $y$ yields:
$$ \partial y = \sin{\delta}\ \partial l  \implies \frac{\partial y}{\partial l}=\sin{\delta}$$
Putting this all together, then it would follow that
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial l} = \cos{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\sin{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
Is this correct? Further, I am a bit concerned that $\delta$ actually has some $x$ dependence based on its definition. Should this affect the relationship between the partial derivatives?
EDIT: Based on the comment from Kurt, it seems that my concern is correct that $\delta=\delta(x)$. I believe the consequence of this is that when you implicitly differentiate the equation solved for $x$, you find:
$$ \partial x=\cos{\delta}\ \partial l - l \sin{\delta} \ \partial x - n \cos{\delta} \ \partial x $$
and hence
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial l} = \frac{\cos{\delta}}{1+l\sin{\delta}+n\cos{\delta}} $$
Is this now the correct procedure for continuing with the other relations?

This is not correct precisely for the reason you are concerned about. What is $\frac{ds}{dx}?$

Here, $s$ is an unknown function of $x,t$ that has to be solved for.

Of $x,\color{red}t,?$ Welcome $t$ to the zoo of unexplained variables!

$t$ represents time in this problem. $(x,z)$ and $(l,n)$ are two differential spatial coordinate frames in which I view the problem - none of these have time dependence although I suppose $\delta$ does.

$\color{red}z,?$ Another one. Whatever you mean by those pairs, these are coordinates that depend on time as soon as $\delta$ does.

Sorry I meant $y$ - there is no $z$. I see though thank you. So should I instead have an additional term in the equation for $\partial_l$ of the form $\frac{\partial t}{\partial l}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$? And then similarly for all the other relations?

Further, should I have terms that include $\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x}$? Take for instance the second to last equation in the edited part. Is that correct or should the second and third terms on the RHS also include $\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x}$?

You have to view the coordinate tranformation as a differentiable mapping between $(x,y)$ and $(l,n),.$ Forget first about a specific form and apply the full chain rule. This will show how the partial derivatives transform. The method is the same as here.
